Solving a system of NExpectations over an implicit function, repeated evaluations to converge to a fixed point(?)
I have the following NExpectations,
mc = NExpectation[Cos[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
ms = NExpectation[Sin[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
qs = NExpectation[Cos[phi[x, y]]*Cos[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
qc = 1-qs;
qsc = NExpectation[Cos[phi[x, y]]*Sin[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];

The coefficient values are given below,
Q1 = 0.9;
Q2 = .5;
Q3 = 0.5;
Q = {{Q1, Q3}, {Q3,Q2}};

The Implicit function is given by
 phi[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[-((1-Lambda)*mc + Sqrt[alpha]*x)*Sin[phi] +((1-Lambda)*ms + Sqrt[alpha]*y)*Cos[phi]- alpha*(C2*Sin[phi]*Sin[phi] - S1*Cos[phi]*Cos[phi]+ (C1-S2)*Cos[phi]*Sin[phi]), {phi, 5.1}][[1]][[2]]

The above function can admit up to four solutions, is there a way I can select a solution, based on a condition?
My aim is find the values of the NExpectations, since they are dependant on each other, I believe  only way to approach is to iteratively run the system(?) till convergence. I start with initial conditions and run the integrals a few times. Is this approach correct?
Further to complicate the problem, the matrix Q also depends on a set of equations comprising of even more integrals, giving a total 9 integrals and 5 equations and one implicit function given below
Q1 = 0.9;
Q2 = .5;
Q3 = 0.5;
Q = {{Q1, Q3}, {Q3,Q2}};
Qinv = Inverse[Q];
detQ = Det[Q];
barQ1 = Q1/detQ;
barQ2 = Q2/detQ;
barQ3 = -Q3/detQ; 
Lambda = 0.6;
alpha = 0.04;
mc = 1;
ms = 0.;
qc = 1;
qs = 0;
qsc = 0.0;
C1 = 0.0;
C2= 0.0;
S1 = 0;
S2 = 1;

phi[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[-((1-Lambda)*mc + Sqrt[alpha]*x)*Sin[phi] +((1-Lambda)*ms + Sqrt[alpha]*y)*Cos[phi]- alpha*(C2*Sin[phi]*Sin[phi] - S1*Cos[phi]*Cos[phi]+ (C1-S2)*Cos[phi]*Sin[phi]), {phi, 5.1}][[1]][[2]]
 mc = NExpectation[Cos[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
ms = NExpectation[Sin[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
qs = NExpectation[Cos[phi[x, y]]*Cos[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
qc = 1-qs;
qsc = NExpectation[Cos[phi[x, y]]*Sin[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
 C1 = ((1-Lambda)/Sqrt[alpha])*NExpectation[(barQ1*x + barQ3*y)*Cos[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
C2 = ((1-Lambda)/Sqrt[alpha])*NExpectation[(barQ3*x + barQ2*y)*Cos[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
S1 = C2;
S2 = ((1-Lambda)/Sqrt[alpha])*NExpectation[(barQ3*x + barQ2*y)*Sin[phi[x, y]],{x,y}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{0,0},Q]];
Q1 = qc*(1-S2)^2 + 2*C2*(1-S2)*qsc + qs*C2^2;
Q2 = qc*S1^2 + 2*S1*(1-C1)*qsc + qs*(1-C1)^2;
Q3 = S1*(1-S2)*qc + (1-S2 - C1 +S1*C2 + S2*C1)*qsc + C2*(1-C1)*qs;
```

